# SignalR Hub client - bypass cloudflare with ClearanceDelegate

Tags: .net, http-headers, signalr, cloudflare

I am trying to bypass the cloudflare check recently implemented over the Bittrex.com signalR hub endpoint.

I am using this utility to create a ClearenceDelegate: https://github.com/elcattivo/CloudFlareUtilities

This is working for my regular HttpRequestMessages, but I am trying to get my hub to connect.

I have attached the _cfduid and cf_clearance cookies, and also added User-Agent header that is identical to initial request, though I still cant get it to connect... I get the same 503 as if I had done nothing.

Is there possibly a way to force the hubConnection obj to use the initial HttpClient or handler?

```
        var handler = new ClearanceHandler();
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://www.bittrex.com/");

        try
        {

            HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://www.bittrex.com/"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get
            };


            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(msg);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
            }



            IEnumerable<string> heads;
            if (msg.Headers.TryGetValues("User-Agent", out heads))
            {
                foreach (string s in heads)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    //Outputs: "Client/1.0"

                    //Add User-Agent header to hubConnection
                    hubConnection.Headers.Add("User-Agent", s);
                }
            }


            hubConnection.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            IEnumerable<string> cookies;

            //set the "_cfduid" and "cf_clearance" cookies we recieved on the hubConnection
            if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("set-cookie", out cookies))
            {
                foreach (var c in cookies)
                {
                    Uri target = new Uri("https://www.bittrex.com/");
                    hubConnection.CookieContainer.SetCookies(target, c);
                }
            }


        }
        catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is CloudFlareClearanceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("CONNECTING");




        //try to connect to the hub with attached cookies and user-agent header:
        await hubConnection.Start();

        btrexHubProxy.On<MarketDataUpdate>("updateExchangeState", update => 
        BtrexRobot.UpdateEnqueue(update));
        //btrexHubProxy.On<SummariesUpdate>("updateSummaryState", update =>  Console.WriteLine("FULL SUMMARY: "));
        btrexHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("coreHub");
```

Comment: im going to try to subclass the signalR DefaultHttpClient, which i will then pass into hubConnection.Start()

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?